# How to calculate the value of x from the series given when n is 12 and P is 10.83?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Let the given series is $$P=\sum^{n}_{t=1}[\frac{1}{(1+x)^t}]$$

I need to solve this for $x$ when $n=12$ and $P=10.83$. When I substitute the values and open the summation then I get this form: $$10.83=\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^3}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^4}+...+\frac{1}{(1+x)^{12}}$$ Here I need the help that how to get x.

Comment: Can you please comment on the use of brackets in the summation?  Does this represent anything, or just used for style?

Comment: $1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1} = \frac{x^n - 1}{x - 1}$

Comment: @138Aspen,  The OP states that value of $n$ should be $12$.  It looks like you used $n = 1$ in your computation.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the algebra, I would recommend computing
$$(1+x)P - P = \left[1-\frac{1}{(1+x)^{12}}\right].$$
$$\implies P = \frac{1}{x}\left[1-\frac{1}{(1+x)^{12}}\right].$$

Now, if we make the substitution $x = y-1$, then
$$P = \frac{1}{y-1}\left[1-\frac{1}{y^{12}}\right]$$
This is much easier to solve for $y$, and the result is the polynomial
$$Py^{13}-(1+P)y^{12}+1 = 0.$$

Newton's method would work great for this based on the graph.

Finally, solve for $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint. I have used the geometric series and reached the final polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Without numerical methods, you can have very simple *approximations* of the equation $$P=\sum^{n}_{t=1}\frac{1}{(1+x)^t}=\frac{1-(x+1)^{-n}}{x}$$ when the value of $P$ is just smaller than $t$.

You know that the solution is very small.

Use the binomial expansion or Taylor series to write
$$\frac{1-(x+1)^{-n}}{x}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty   \binom{-n}{k+1}\,x^k$$ and use [power series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html).

This would give
$$x=y+\frac{n+2}{3} y^2\left(1+\frac{5 n+7}{12}  y +\frac{(17 n^2+44 n+29}{90} y^2+O(y^3)   \right)$$

where $$y=\frac{2 (n-P)}{n (n+1)}$$

For your specific case where $n=12$, $P=\frac {1083}{100}$, $y=\frac {3}{200}$, the above truncated series would give, as an approximation
$$x=\frac{25833321}{1600000000}=\color{red}{0.01614}58$$